# Convert rows into columns with conditions

Tags: excel, transpose

I've the following excel which needs to be transposed to columns. I have tried using the built-in formula and hte pivot table but that did not help me much since the data is in a single column and I am looking for transposing to multiple columns.

Excel: (all data in single column)

```
ABC1
F1
D1
Sym1
ABC2
See Link2
ABC3
F3
D3
Sym3
ABC4
See Link4
ABC5
See Link5
```

The output should be like:

```
ABC      Functions      Description       Sym        See Link
ABC1      F1                D1            Sym1
ABC2                                                  See Link1
ABC3      F3                D3            Sym3
ABC4                                                  See Link4
ABC5                                                  See Link5
```

See that when 'See Link' is present for the row data, none of the functions, descriptions and syms are present and vice versa.

Comment: Since there are blank elements you need to be much more specific about how you expect this to work.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out. Used G script in googlesheet to get this right. For anyone looking for code, here's it:

```
function run() {
  var inputSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var outputSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Description");
  var rows = new Array(new Array());

  var values = inputSheet.getRange(1, 1, inputSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  Logger.log(values.length);
  var j = 0;
  var endOfRow = false;
      var singleRow = new Array();

  for (var row in values) {

   for (var col in values[row]) {
     var value = values[row][col];

     if(value.indexOf("F") != -1) {
      singleRow[1] = value;
     }
     else if(value.indexOf("D") != -1) {
       singleRow[2] = value;
     }
     else if(value.indexOf("See Link") != -1) {
       singleRow[4] = value;
       endOfRow = true;
     }
     else if(value.indexOf("Sym") != -1) {
       singleRow[3] = value;
       endOfRow = true;
     } 
     else {
       singleRow[0] = value;

     }

    }

    if(endOfRow) {
      rows[j] = singleRow;
       j++;
      endOfRow = false;
      var singleRow = new Array();
    }

  }
  for(var d=2; d < rows.length; d++) {
      var singleRow = rows[d];

      for(var f = 0; f < singleRow.length; f++) {
        if(singleRow[f] == undefined) {
          outputSheet.getRange(d, f+1).setValue("");
        } else {
          outputSheet.getRange(d, f+1).setValue(singleRow[f]);
        }
      }
    }

}
```